# Is a any controlled invariant subspace also a controllability subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

If the system 
$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu \\
y=Cx$, where $x\in R^n, u \in R^M, y\in R^P$ is controllable, can we then say that any controlled invariant subspace is also a controllability subspace?

I would argue the following way:

1. The system in controllable if $\Gamma=[B\space AB\space ... \space A^{n-1}B]$ has full rank, namely $rank(\Gamma)=n$.
2. a controllable subspace is defined as $<A|Im \space B>=span\{B,AB,...,A^{n-1}B\}$
3. by definition we know that subspace $ R$ is a controllability subspace if it is (A,B)-invariant and if there're F and G such that $R=<A+BF|Im \space BG>$
4. A subspace $R$ is a controllability subspace if and and only if there is F such that $R=<A+BF|Im B \cap R>$.$\\$ 
   now if there is a $G$ s.t. $Im\space B \cap R=Im BG$ and  and we insert this in in the controllable subspace $R=<A+BF|Im \space BG>$ we get 
   $R=<A+BF|Im \space B\cap R>$ which is the reachability subspace.
   So I'd say the statement is true but I am stuck at this point...

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of the notation <•,•> ?

Comment: sure, the notation $<A|Im B>$ denotes the minimal A-invariant subspace that contains the Image B.

Comment: I'm not sure what $(A, B)$-invariant is and how you can use $\operatorname{Im}B \cap R$ before $R$ is defined. But controllable subspace is state-feedback invariant as long as $G$ is full rank. With your notation it can be written as $<A | \operatorname{Im}B> = <A+BF | \operatorname{Im}BG>$ for any $F$ and full rank $G$.

Comment: Eigenvector interpretation of
(A, B)-invariant and controllability subspaces given in "Computation of Suprema1 (A,B)-Invariant
and Controllability Subspaces " by B.C. Moore and A.J.C Laub is a very good reference I guess. And I too think a controlled invariant subspace is a controllability subspace